# Null model of images from an ok Retrofit response

Tags: java, android, model, retrofit, android-glide

I have an okay response received by retrofit and I'm able to show the model attributes on my view except for one list of images. I am getting a null value from it although I see the log has the required JSON data. As it is a list of images, I'm using Glide to display them and on the log says `W/Glide: Load failed for null with size [0x0] class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model`

The attribute I'm trying to access is `promotionalimages` in the class `Data`.

Do let me know if further information is required.

What am I doing wrong?

model:

[RestaurantModel](https://pastebin.com/mbEyX4Fa)

part of my activity where im displaying the response:

```
Call<RestaurantModel> call = apiInterface.getRestaurant(getSharedPreference.getToken(), identifier);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<RestaurantModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<RestaurantModel> call, @NonNull Response<RestaurantModel> response) {
            restaurant = response.body();

            rName.setText(restaurant.getData().getName());
            ratingtxt.setText(String.format("%s", restaurant.getData().getAvgRatingCount()));
            Glide.with(context).load(restaurant.getData().getPromotionalimages().get(0).getPromotionalPicture()).apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform().placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)).into(holder.image);
```

the response:

```
{
"data": {
    "identifier": "0464eee2-5160-40e7-8ae0-77e7484fe251",
    "name": "Apple Lab",
    "phonenumber": "11116425300",
    "start_time": "7:00 AM",
    "end_time": "1:00 PM",
    "created_at": "2018-07-30 20:10:05",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-30 20:11:00",
    "reviews_count": 0,
    "avgRatingCount": 0,
    "categoryCount": 0,
    "subCategoryCount": 0,
    "totalItemCount": 0,
    "availableItemCount": 0,
    "isOpen": 1,
    "logo": "https://x.co/storage/logoandcover/0464eee2-5160-40e7-8ae0-77e7484fe251/15b5f1dc0ef064.png",
    "cover": "https://x.co/storage/logoandcover/0464eee2-5160-40e7-8ae0-77e7484fe251/15b5f1df0e2f78.png",
    "galleryimages": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "identifier": "0464eee2-5160-40e7-8ae0-77e7484fe2511",
            "restaurant_id": 7,
            "gallery_picture": "https://x.co/storage/galleryimages/0464eee2-5160-40e7-8ae0-77e7484fe251/15b5f1e2cc80aa.png",
            "created_at": "2018-07-30 20:18:20",
            "updated_at": "2018-07-30 20:18:20"
        }
    ],
    "location": {
        "house": "x",
        "road": "x",
        "details": "x",
        "country": "x",
        "created_at": "2018-07-30 20:12:28",
        "updated_at": "2018-07-30 20:12:28",
        "cityName": "x",
        "areaName": "x"
    },
    "promotionalimages": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "identifier": "0464eee2-5160-40e7-8ae0-77e7484fe2511",
            "restaurant_id": 7,
            "promotional_picture": "https://x.co/storage/promotionalimages/0464eee2-5160-40e7-8ae0-77e7484fe251/15b5f1ec0afffb.png",
            "created_at": "2018-07-30 20:20:48",
            "updated_at": "2018-07-30 20:20:48"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "identifier": "0464eee2-5160-40e7-8ae0-77e7484fe2512",
            "restaurant_id": 7,
            "promotional_picture": "https://x.co/storage/promotionalimages/0464eee2-5160-40e7-8ae0-77e7484fe251/15b5f1ec13a9b7.png",
            "created_at": "2018-07-30 20:20:49",
            "updated_at": "2018-07-30 20:20:49"
        }
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "id": 25,
            "restaurant_id": 7,
            "name": "Food Quality",
            "created_at": "2018-07-30 20:11:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-07-30 20:11:00",
            "favoritesCount": 0,
            "isFavorited": false,
            "favorites": []
        },
        {
            "id": 26,
            "restaurant_id": 7,
            "name": "Customer Service",
            "created_at": "2018-07-30 20:11:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-07-30 20:11:00",
            "favoritesCount": 0,
            "isFavorited": false,
            "favorites": []
        },
        {
            "id": 27,
            "restaurant_id": 7,
            "name": "Environment",
            "created_at": "2018-07-30 20:11:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-07-30 20:11:00",
            "favoritesCount": 0,
            "isFavorited": false,
            "favorites": []
        },
        {
            "id": 28,
            "restaurant_id": 7,
            "name": "Food Pricing",
            "created_at": "2018-07-30 20:11:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-07-30 20:11:00",
            "favoritesCount": 0,
            "isFavorited": false,
            "favorites": []
        }
    ],
    "reviews": [],
    "categories": [],
    "menus": [],
    "profile": {
        "id": 7,
        "restaurant_id": 7,
        "logo": "https://x.co/storage/logoandcover/0464eee2-5160-40e7-8ae0-77e7484fe251/15b5f1dc0ef064.png",
        "cover": "https://x.co/storage/logoandcover/0464eee2-5160-40e7-8ae0-77e7484fe251/15b5f1df0e2f78.png",
        "payable_amount": "0.00",
        "payment_received": "0.00",
        "last_paid": "2018-07-30 14:17:21",
        "score": "100.00",
        "vat_reg_number": null,
        "created_at": "2018-07-30 20:11:00",
        "updated_at": "2018-07-30 20:17:21",
        "status": "Bronze"
    }}}
```

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JSON response, I see:

> ```
> "promotionalimages": [
>     {
>         ...
>         "promotional_picture": "https://x.co/storage/promotionalimages/0464eee2-5160-40e7-8ae0-77e7484fe251/15b5f1ec13a9b7.png",
>     }
> ]
> ```

However, in your model classes, I see:

> ```
> public static class Promotionalimage {
>     ...
>     private String promotionalPicture;
> }
> ```

These two things don't have the same name: the JSON is using `promotional_picture` but the Java is using `promotionalPicture`. It's possible that you have some other code set up to convert from underscores to camel case, but I bet you don't.

There are two ways to fix. I'd recommend adding the `@SerializedName` annotation:

```
public static class Promotionalimage {
    ...
    @SerializedName("promotional_picture")
    private String promotionalPicture;
}
```

but you could also simply change the name of the Java field:

```
public static class Promotionalimage {
    ...
    private String promotional_picture;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. It works now. For some reason, jsonschema2pojo.org didn't convert the variable name properly. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Just try with Picasso

```
Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(link)
                    .into(yourView)
```

Comment: I do the same and it works but do you know exact problem here?